# How to change Woocommerce breadcrumbs content?

Tags: filters, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to customize the breadcrumbs directly from PHP. Some of the pages are generated dynamically and do not exist in the database, therefore i must automatically put them in the breadcrumbs with some sort of PHP script.

I don't need to change default stuff, like homepage url, separators, etc...but i actually need to manually put some pages in the breadcrumbs. I was trying with some filterings and some hooks.

[I've read the documentation](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/) but it just explains how to change default stuff.

How can i change the actual content of the breadcrumbs?

I tried this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 'change_breadcrumb' );
function change_breadcrumb( $defaults ) {
    // Change the breadcrumb home text from 'Home' to 'Appartment'
    //do something
    return $defaults;
}
```

But the `//do something` never executes. It's like if that filter never gets called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is due to the fact, that your filter `woocommerce_breadcrumb` doesn't even exist.

This filter here works and pulls out all the elements, that are currently in the breadcrumb (as an array):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'change_breadcrumb' );
function change_breadcrumb( $crumbs ) {
    var_dump( $crumbs );

    return $crumbs;
}
```

And this filter pulls out the `main term` (as an object).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_main_term', 'change_breadcrumb' );
function change_breadcrumb( $main_term ) {
    var_dump( $main_term );

    return $main_term;
}
```

The 'main term' is just the first element that is returned by this function ([reference](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Breadcrumb.html#7-350)):

```
$terms = wc_get_product_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat', array( 'orderby' => 'parent', 'order' => 'DESC' ) )
```

See the [Action and Filter Hook Reference](https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) by woothemes for all hooks & filters.